# Call function on several lines

Tags: vimrc, repeated-commands, functions

I have a [function](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7761/how-to-restore-the-position-of-the-cursor-after-executing-a-normal-command) that changes the 6th caracter of a line to a dollar symbol (`$`).

I want it to be performed on several lines, so I naively did a "while" loop using a counter (as shown under).

But I have the feeling that there must be a much simpler, more "vim-esque" way to do that -- my function seems a bit complicated for such a simple task. Maybe I'm wrong, but I would appreciate any simplification/comments.

My current function is :

```
function! DollarSplit(nlines)
   let current_pos = getpos(".")
   let a:count = 0
   while a:count < a:nlines 
      normal! 6|r$j
      a:count += 1
   endwhile
   call setpos(".", current_pos)
endfunction
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function! DollarSplit() range
   let current_pos = getpos(".")
   execute a:firstline . "," . a:lastline . "normal! 6|r$"
   call setpos(".", current_pos)
endfunction
```

See `:help function-range-example`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is more in the spirit of what I was looking for, though @Nobe4's regexp was perfect too (and his explanations as well)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following replace:

```
function! DollarSplit(nlines)
   let current_pos = getpos(".")

   execute ',+'.a:nlines.'s/^\(.\{5}\).\(.*\)/\1$\2/g'

   call setpos(".", current_pos)
endfunction
```

Decomposing:

```
execute '      " prepare a command
,+             " the command will operate on lines from current to
'.a:nlines.'   " current+a:nlines
s/^            " the command is a substitution, starting at start of line
\(.\{5}\)      " capture the first 5 characters into a group (1)
.              " match any 6th character
\(.*\)         " capture the remaining of the line into a group (2)
/\1$\2         " replace by group 1 $ group 2
/g'            " end the substitution
```

This will basically create two matching group, surrounding the char you want to replace, and then restore the two groups with a `$` inside.

References:

- `:h ranges`
- `:h substitute`

Comment: ... I was trying to explain the parts I understood and the part I did not in your regexp, thank you very much haha

Comment: do you understand everything now ? :)

Comment: I think so yes, thank you very much ! I did not know about the "groups" usage, it seems very useful. Two last little questions if you have time : 
1. `*` means "all that remains in the line" ?
 2. One can not add spaces inside the regexp I suppose (to make it more readable for a newbie like me) as they would be interpretated as litteral white spaces ?

Comment: `*` means `any number of` so `.*` means `any number of anything`. I'm not sure about the regex formatting, but once you grasp the concept it shouldn't be too hard to read ;)