# Function call makes cursor jump to beginning of file

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I'm writing a function that should run a linter and then populate the location list with appropriate linting messages.

The problem is that when I call the function (by running `:Phpcs`), the cursor jumps to the top of the file, which is undesired, since I plan on running the linter every time I save the file and then check the location list before committing any changes to the repository.

I have cut everything unneeded away and the following is what is left in my `.vimrc`

I have tested the function in both Vim 8.2.43000 and Nvim 0.6.1 - Both installed from Homebrew on Mac OS Big Sur.

```
function! RunPhpcs()
    echo "Hello world"
endfunction

command! Phpcs execute RunPhpcs()
```

The desired functionality is that when I run the function it does *not* jump to the beginning of the file.

I have read through a somewhat similar, but different, [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7761/how-to-restore-the-position-of-the-cursor-after-executing-a-normal-command) and tried both `getpos()`/`setpos()` and `winsaveview()`/`winrestview()` but with no luck.

What am I missing to make the function call *not* jump to the beginning of the file when executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe could you use `call` instead of `execute`:

```
function! RunPhpcs()
    echo "Hello world"
endfunction

command! Phpcs call RunPhpcs()
```

The `execute` function moves the cursor to the result of the evaluated expression. If your function doesn't explicitly returns a value it returns 0 and the cursor is moved at the start of the file.

You can experiment that by running `execute 2`.

Comment: Using `call` instead of `execute` solved the problem! - Thanks!